# python: count events by certain id

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have the following array[][]:

```
import numpy as np

data = np.array([
    [20,  0,  1],
    [22,  0,  1],
    [31,  0,  0],
    [49,  1,  0],
    [96,  1,  0],
    [57,  2,  1],
    [45,  3,  0],
    [12,  3,  0],
    [14,  3,  1],
    [33,  4,  1],
    [34,  4,  1],
    [15,  4,  1]
])
```

Lets call the columns: `a, b, c` by the above order where `b is id`.
I want to count the number of 1's in the `c` column by the id's in column `b`
this will result the following 2 columns array (1st column is unique(b) and 2nd column is counted 1's from `c` per that id):

```
data = np.array([
    [4,  3],
    [0,  2],
    [2,  1],
    [3,  1],
    [1,  0]
])
```

You can also see it is sorted by the counted 1's in the `c` column

My idea to solve this problem was to create a dictionery: `{ id1:counted 1's id2:counted 1's ... }` by the ids in the b column and iterate over the array and count the number of 1's per id and put it as value per key in the dictionary, then create an array out of the result and sort it by the 2nd column.

Is there any pythonic easy and better way to do so ?

another case scenario is where i want to add all the integers in the c column per id, so for:

```
data = np.array([
    [20,  0,  2],
    [22,  0,  1],
    [31,  0,  0],
    [49,  1,  0],
    [96,  1,  0],
    [57,  2,  1],
    [45,  3,  0],
    [12,  3,  5],
    [14,  3,  1],
    [33,  4,  1],
    [34,  4,  3],
    [15,  4,  4]
])
```

I will get

```
data = np.array([
    [4,  8],
    [3,  6],
    [0,  3],
    [2,  1],
    [1,  0]
])
```

Comment: Would the third column always have 1s and 0s only?

Comment: Yes. but we can just add the number in c to a "sum"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`np.bincount`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html) -

```
count = np.bincount(data[:,1],data[:,2]==1)
out = np.column_stack((np.unique(data[:,1]),count))
```

If you need it in descending order of count, we need to add two more lines of code -

```
sidx = count.argsort()[::-1]
out = np.column_stack((sidx,count[sidx]))
```

Alternatively, if you need it in descending order of count and also keep the order, use `argsort` with `'mergesort'`, like so -

```
sidx = (-count).argsort(kind='mergesort')
out = np.column_stack((sidx,count[sidx]))
```

Sample run -

Input array :

```
In [36]: data
Out[36]: 
array([[20,  0,  1],
       [22,  0,  1],
       [31,  0,  0],
       [49,  1,  0],
       [96,  1,  0],
       [57,  2,  1],
       [45,  3,  0],
       [12,  3,  0],
       [14,  3,  1],
       [33,  4,  1],
       [34,  4,  1],
       [15,  4,  1]])
```

Part 1 :

```
In [37]: count = np.bincount(data[:,1],data[:,2]==1)
    ...: out = np.column_stack((np.unique(data[:,1]),count))
    ...: 

In [38]: out
Out[38]: 
array([[ 0.,  2.],
       [ 1.,  0.],
       [ 2.,  1.],
       [ 3.,  1.],
       [ 4.,  3.]])
```

Part 2 :

```
In [39]: sidx = count.argsort()[::-1]
    ...: out = np.column_stack((sidx,count[sidx]))
    ...: 

In [40]: out
Out[40]: 
array([[ 4.,  3.],
       [ 0.,  2.],
       [ 3.,  1.],
       [ 2.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  0.]])
```

Part 3 :

```
In [48]: sidx = (-count).argsort(kind='mergesort')

In [49]: np.column_stack((sidx,count[sidx]))
Out[49]: 
array([[ 4.,  3.],
       [ 0.,  2.],
       [ 2.,  1.],
       [ 3.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  0.]])
```

---

To add all the integers in the c column per id, simply skip that check against `1` -

```
count = np.bincount(data[:,1],data[:,2])
```

Comment: Thats working great. What if in the c column i had any integer and I'd like to count them (instead of just count +1 for the 1 in c)

Comment: @EranMoshe Replace `1` in `data[:,2]==1` as used at `np.bincount()` step with that integer?

Comment: I mean if there was 9 in c i would like to count 9 and not 1

Comment: @EranMoshe That's what I answered, do : `np.bincount(data[:,1],data[:,2]==9)`.

Comment: for [[1, 0, 5], [3, 0, 4]] i would like to get [0, 9]

Comment: @EranMoshe There's no `9` in   `[[1, 0, 5], [3, 0, 4]]`. It's not clear to me what you have in mind. Consider making another sample case with that scenario and add to the question with the expected output.

Comment: I've added the example above

Comment: @EranMoshe Edited answer for that.

Comment: Thanks! After I've read the documentation of bincount(weights=) I  feel like an idiot